Compiler not complaining when importing constant that doesn't exist
I am writing a Node application using TypeScript.
When using npm run dev, the following code compiles without problems and prints undefined at runtime.
index.ts:
import { a } from './some-file.ts';
console.log(`the value of a is: ${a}`);

some-file.ts:
export const b = 2;

Even npm run lint fails to spot anything unusual.
My package.json is:
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "watch": {
    "lint": {
      "patterns": [
        "src"
      ],
      "extensions": "ts",
      "quiet": false
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "tsx watch src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "npx eslint src/",
    "lint:watch": "npm-watch lint"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "kysely": "^0.27.4",
    "pg": "^8.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.5.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "globals": "^15.6.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.13.0",
    "tsx": "^4.15.7",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.14.1"
  }
}

My tsconfig.json is:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",                                  
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}


I cannot reproduce, given your setup I get the expected error: "error TS2305: Module '"./some-file.ts"' has no exported member 'a'." I also get the expected "error TS5097: An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled." which you don't mention. Also, not the DV, but is there anything else you can add on this?

@JaredSmith edited my question; I should have clarified that this situation (i.e. no reported errors) arises only with target dev. I.e. npm run dev.

It appears that tsx does not actually do type-checking, presumably for performance reasons. If you want types checked when starting your app, you may want to use ts-node instead.

@JaredSmith thanks. I posted an answer cause I had to tweak some other stuff as well to make this work. At any rate if feels wrong that a TS runtime that's supposed to be used during development doesn't do type checks.

Thanks to the comment by @JaredSmith I ended up doing the following (to ensure that ts-node automatically recompiles when files change):
npm i --D ts-node nodemon

I then defined the dev (continuous compilation) target as:
"dev": "nodemon src/index.ts"

Then it become necessary to say:
import { a } from './some-file';

... instead of:
import { a } from './some-file.ts';

Using "allowImportingTsExtensions": true instead, sort of worked but then it caused other complications down the road so I had to abort this approach.
Finally, even the above setup failed with SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module so, based on this answer, I had to do eventually edit my tsconfig.json to look like so:
{
  "ts-node": {
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node
    // same as the --compilerOptions flag and the TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS environment variable
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
     }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",                                  
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  }
}

For some weird reason the above setup works even though the "type" in the top-level compilerOptions is set to ESNext whereas the "type" in the compilerOptions under "ts-node" has to be set to "commonjs". At this point it all feels too magical to be honest.
